# How incorporate random-float into a command? NETLOGO

Tags: if-statement, random, model, netlogo

```
To eat ;to kill prey and eat it
  let kill one-of prey-here in-radius smell
  ;need to code in a variable for success too
  if kill != nobody
    [ask kill [ die ]
      set energy energy + 10000]
end
```

At present this is my command for my turtle to eat prey when they run into them on the map. 
I want to add a variable so that there is a chance they don't get to eat. I know I need to use `random-float 1`

```
if random float is > .4 [what happens]
```

but i do not know where to add it into my eat commands so that it works.

can someone please advise?

Comment: see answer to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474886/hunt-success-netlogo. Voting to close this as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hunt success netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474886/hunt-success-netlogo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `if random-float 1 > .4 [do something]`